# Noun form of "contested"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was writing an online post, and I found myself wanting to write the word "contestation", the 'noun' form of "contested".

Is there such a derivation of "to contest", that could go in the noun slot of a Mad Lib? In other words, fill in the blank:

> The claim was contested. There was a ________ about the claim.

If there is no such form of the verb "contest", then what other words are a good match?

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/contest (Click on "fight, struggle" in the tabs at the top.)

Answer (score 3):

## Dispute

Is the word that most naturally fits your example sentence I would say.

> An argument or disagreement, especially an official one...

[Ref : Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dispute)

Answer (score 0):

I'd usually say *dispute*, *argument*, or *disagreement*.

Comment: Please add dictionary definitions and links to show why these words answer the question.